# How to retrieve blog post from Blogger to Android app?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an Android application that extract blog post from a blog http://heroesofmalaysia.blogspot.com/ to display in the application. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Blogger has an API. Check out the docs here: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BVB said, you can use the Google Blogger API.

1) Use this link for the how to use https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using

2) You will need to authenticate you app with the api to be able to communicate with using `OAuth`

3) Use the URL format as described in the link to construct your request e.g. get a specific post, create post, get replies....etc

4) Receive the response in a `JSON` Format and parse it to display whatever you want.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use JSoup to parse the HTML you get from the server: http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have done that but not in the way you want!
Actually I have added 20 articles in my app.
**HOW**

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.articleWebview);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(backGroundColor);  
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/articlesExplore/astral_projection.html);
```

[image]

As you can see i pasted the HTML files in the assets and then it it show in webview.

Let's have a look, [image]

And also, you can do that using google drive or firebase storage or onedrive. Save those file in the cloud storage and paste the link in the loadurl(LINK); Whenever you want to edit the pages, then edit them in blogger and paste the code in the html files. This is useful when you have like 100 posts (I had seven only).